# Swift Dictionary confusion

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

Say I have

```
var dict = parseJSON(getJSON(url)) // This results in an NSDictionary
```

Why is

```
let a = dict["list"]![1]! as NSDictionary
let b = a["temp"]!["min"]! as Float
```

allowed, and this:

```
let b = dict["list"]![1]!["temp"]!["min"]! as Float
```

results in an error:

> Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'

Please explain why this happens, note that I'm new to Swift and have no experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dict["list"]![1]!` returns an object that is not known yet (`AnyObject`) and without the proper cast the compiler cannot know that the returned object is a dictionary

In your first example you properly cast the returned value to a dictionary and only then you can extract the value you expect.

Answer (score 2):

To amend the answer from @giorashc: use explicit casting like

```
let b = (dict["list"]![1]! as NSDictionary)["temp"]!["min"]! as Float
```

But splitting it is better readable in those cases.